# $X$ is a $T_2$ space. Let $f\in C_0(X), g\in C_c(X)$. Prove that, $fg\in C_c(X)$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Here $C_0(X)$ denotes the collection of all such continuous maps $f:X\to\Bbb{C}$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists $ compact set $K$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon\ \forall x\in K^c$.

And  $C_c(X)$ denotes the collection of all such continuous maps $g:X\to\Bbb{C}$ such that $\text{supp}(g):=\overline{\{x\in X|g(x)\ne 0\}}$ is compact.

It's easy to see that $C_c(X)\subset C_0(X)$.

Suppose $f\in C_c(X)$. Then $\text{supp}(fg)\subset \text{supp}(f)\cup\text{supp}(g)$ and since union of two compact sets is compact and $\text{supp}(fg)$ is closed, $\text{supp}(fg)$  is compact, hence $fg\in C_c(X)$.

But I'm stuck with the case $f\in C_0(X)\setminus C_c(X)$?

Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: In other words, $C_c(X)$ is an ideal in $C_0(X)$. Additional question: Is this ideal closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is continuous and $g\in C_c(X)$. Since the product of two complex numbers is non-zero if and only if both numbers are non-zero,
$$\{x\in X\,|\,f(x)g(x)\neq 0\}\subseteq\{x\in X\,|\,g(x)\neq 0\}\subseteq\overline{\{x\in X\,|\,g(x)\neq 0\}}.$$
Take the closure of the left-hand side:
$$\operatorname{supp}{(fg)}=\overline{\{x\in X\,|\,f(x)g(x)\neq 0\}}\subseteq\overline{\{x\in X\,|\,g(x)\neq 0\}}=\operatorname{supp}{(g)}.$$
The set $\operatorname{supp}{(fg)}$ is a closed subset of the compact set $\operatorname{supp}{(g)}$ and hence itself compact. Clearly, the product function $fg$ is continuous. Therefore, $fg\in C_c(X)$.

---

Note that $X$ need not even be Hausdorff and $f$ merely needs to be continuous—not necessarily in $C_0(X)$—for this conclusion.